# Why matplotlib does not plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I started to learn MatPlotLib using [this](http://www.loria.fr/~rougier/teaching/matplotlib/) tutorial for beginners. Here is the first example.

```
from pylab import *
X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256,endpoint=True)
C,S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)
```

If I write these 3 lines into my python file and execute it in the command line (by typing `python file_name.py`), nothing happens. No error message, no plot.

Does anybody know why I do not see the plot?

**ADDED**

Of course I need to use `show`. But even if I add the following 3 lines:

```
plot(X,C)
plot(X,S)
show()
```

it still does no generate anything.

**ADDED**

Here are the lines that I use now:

```
import pylab as p
C = [1,2,3,4]
S = [10, 20, 30, 10]
p.plot(C,S)
p.show()
```

I still have the same result (nothing).

Comment: don't you have to show it at the end using show() ?

Comment: @Roman are you using Ubuntu 12.10? For me everything was working on ubuntu 12.04 but as soon as I moved to 12.10 everything, plots stopped showing up. I am assuming its a distro related issue in my case at-least. savefig(filename) still works though.

Comment: @Shashank Singh, no, I use 12.04.

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt and then plt.show() ?

Comment: @Dan, it does not help. I still have no result.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It could be a problem with the backend.
What is the output of 
`python -c 'import matplotlib; import matplotlib.pyplot; print(matplotlib.backends.backend)'`?

If it is the 'agg' backend, what you see is the expected behaviour as it is a non-interactive backend that does not show anything to the screen, but work with plt.savefig(...).
You should switch to, e.g., TkAgg or Qt4Agg to be able to use `show`. You can do it in the matplotlib.rc file.

@shashank: I run matplotlib both on 12.04 and 12.10 without problems. In both cases I use the Qt4Agg backend. If you don't have the matplotlibrc set, the default backend is used.
I'm sure that for Precise matplotlib repo was built with TkAgg. If the Quantal version has been built with e.g. Agg, then that would explain the difference

Comment: thank you for the answer. Now I use `plt.savefig('name.png')` and `os.system('eog name.png &')` and get what I need. To be honest I do not know what "the 'agg' backend" means, but now I have everything what I need (the working solution). Thanks.

Comment: [here](http://mural.uv.es/parmur/matplotlib.pdf) you can find an explanation of what a backend is (sec 1.3). Your solution looks overly complicated when you have an in build mechanism to show the figure. Give a look to [this page](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) to learn about the matplotlibrc and how does it work. The best option would be to dump it into `~/.matplotlib/` and play with the backends untill you don't get `show` working (it's the first entry in the matplotlibrc file).

Comment: You can find where the matplotlibrc file is by running:
`import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`

See more here: http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Comment: Using 14.04 Ubuntu was able to fix the problem using Qt4Agg.

Comment: And why not just use matplotlib.use('Agg') at the beginning?

Comment: I fixed this by using `matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')` before importing plt. This of course is because my mpl was compiled with qt4 support, however thing it defaulted to the agg backend when I launched python.

Comment: It was TKAgg for me, still did not plot. What may be the reason?

Comment: I tried Qt4Agg and got `Failed to import any qt binding`

Comment: You probably don't have Qt4 installed. Nowadays I would use `Qt5Agg`, though

Answer (score 14):

You need to call the function:

```
show()
```

to be more exact:

```
pylab.show()
```

and even better don't use:

```
from pylab import *
```

rather do:

```
import pylab as p:
```

and then:

```
X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256,endpoint=True)
C,S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)

p.plot(C,S)
p.show()
```

Comment: sorry my question was incomplete (I have edited it). Even if I use `show`, it does not produce anything.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding. I use Jupyter and this worked for me.

```
  %matplotlib inline
```