# Plot matplotlib by running python file

Tags: python, matplotlib

So there was [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558843/why-matplotlib-does-not-plot) talking about why matplotlib does not show when executing

```
python myfile.py
```

The most popular answer was about `resetting matplotlibrc` file. What would need to be reset in this file?

Also, some suggest to include `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` in the import. Below is my python file:

```
#myfile.py

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def dyn_draw():
    x = np.linspace(0, 6 * np.pi, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)

    plt.ion()

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    line1, = ax.plot(x, y, 'r-')  # Returns a tuple of line objects, thus the comma

    for phase in np.linspace(0, 10 * np.pi, 500):
        line1.set_ydata(np.sin(x + phase))
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dyn_draw()
```

Running that with `python myfile.py`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

Another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811545/importerror-cannot-load-backend-tkagg-which-requires-the-tk-interactive-fra) discussed this error. But the solution still does not work (i.e. restarting the kernel).

How to plot this particular python code with the `python` command?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run matplotlib interatively in a non-interactive environment. The code compiles, but errors at run-time because you running a script.

Have you tried running this in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)? The resource provides free (to a certain point) GPU usage and block coding for interactive visualizations.

Best of luck :)